# purchaseRecord в MKStoreKit всегда равна Null

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchases

Я использую **[MKStoreKit](https://github.com/MugunthKumar/MKStoreKit)** (версия 6) для покупки Auto-renewable subscription в приложении. Приложение успешно покупает подписку, но в свойстве `purchaseRecord` класса **MKStoreKit** идентификатору моего продукта всегда соответствует значение `Null`. Вот так выглядит вывод `purchaseRecord`:

```
purchaseRecord: {
SKOrigBundleRef = "1.0";
"com.cName.aName.AutoSubscription" = "<null>";
}
```

Насколько я понимаю, вместо `null` моему ID продукта должна соответствовать дата его истечения. Подскажите, почему это может быть?

Или как мне написать самостоятельно метод, который проверяет, не истекла ли подписка в данный момент?

Comment: пробовали `- (NSDate *)expiryDateForProduct:(NSString *)productId;`?

Comment: Да, пробовал, падает, так как в `purchaseRecord` моему ID соответствует `null`.

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko Не подскажете, что это за `SKOrigBundleRef` у меня в `purchaseRecord`? Его у меня в MKStoreKitConfigs.plist нет, и я не пойму, как он туда попал, и что это. Подозреваю, что что-то стандартное.

Comment: предположу, что версия покупки, если например, вы захотите поменять цену в будущем.

Comment: а если поменять тип на non-renewable дата появляется?

Comment: наткнулся на информацию, что auto-renewable могут использоваться только в приложениях для newsstand либо в приложениях типа business или productvity. http://savvyapps.com/blog/getting-started-with-auto-renewable-subscriptions-in-ios